# Use generic type inside InjectionToken

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible de to use generic type inside an InjectionToken in Angular ?

Here my code :

My InjectionToken where I want to pass a generic type **TOptionValue** :

```
export const OPTION_SELECTION_HANDLER = new InjectionToken<OptionSelectionHandler<TOptionValue>>('OPTION_SELECTION_HANDLER');
```

Where I get the error : *Cannot find name 'TOptionValue'*

A part of my component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-option',
  templateUrl: './option.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [{ provide: OPTION_SELECTION_HANDLER, useExisting: OptionComponent }],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class OptionComponent<TOptionValue> implements OptionSelectionHandler<TOptionValue> {


  @ViewChild('contentWrapper') contentRef: ElementRef;

  @Input()
  disabled = false;

  @Input()
  value: TOptionValue;


  @Input() set selected(selected: boolean) {
    this._selected = selected;
    selected ? this.renderer.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'selected') : this.renderer.removeClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'selected')
    this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
  }
  get selected() : boolean {
    return this._selected;
  }

  _selected: boolean;

  @Output()
  selectedChange = new EventEmitter<TOptionValue>();

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elementRef: ElementRef, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  onSelectOption() {
    if (this.disabled) {
      return;
    }
    this.selected = !this.selected;
    this.selectedChange.emit(this.value);
    this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
  }

  getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }

  setValue(value: TOptionValue): void {
    this.value = value;
    this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
  }

  isSelected(): boolean {
    return this.selected;
  }
  setSelected(selected: boolean): void {
    this.selected = selected;
    this.selectedChange.emit(this.value);
  }
  getContentRef(): ElementRef<any> {
    return this.contentRef;
  }

}
```

My interface :

```
export interface OptionSelectionHandler<TOptionValue> {
  value: TOptionValue;
  selected: boolean;
  selectedChange: EventEmitter<TOptionValue>;
  getContentRef(): ElementRef<any>;
}
```

So currently, I have no idea how to pass the 'TOptionValue' to my InjectionToken.

Comment: It seems that is not possible to pass generic type to an injection token at provider level.
So I writed something like new InjectionToken<OptionSelectionHandler<any>>('OPTION_SELECTION_HANDLER');